# Svg image changes size after setting transform rotate

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-animate

I've made a svg with a car (image) that follows the mouse and keeps it nose to the center of a circle.

This works very well in Windows. (tested on Chrome, Firefox, Edge).

---

**The problem**

When the position changes and the rotation is set, the car changes size for no reason. This happens (I think) on IOS divices (tested on Macbook - Safari and iPhone - Safari & Chrome)

The position is simply changed by setting the `x` and `y` of the image. The rotation (what I think is causes the problem) is changed by setting the attribute `transform`.

```
image.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', (xy.x - (12 * 0.25)));
image.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', (xy.y - (5.4 / 2)));
image.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + (180 - angle) + ',' + xy.x + ',' + xy.y + ') ');
```

I've made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/065o4xke/3/) that toggles the car when clicking a `button`. Please try it in Safari and Chrome to see the difference.

https://jsfiddle.net/065o4xke/3/

Comment: I'm not very sure why you are reseting the values for the x and y attributes. Instead of resetting the values for the x and y  you may only rotate the car around the center of the circle (21,21) like so: `image.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', 'rotate(' + (180 - angle) + ',21,21) ');` If this is not what you need please explain why you need to reset the values for the x and y.

Comment: @enxaneta The car needs to move allong the whole circle with it's nose always pointed to the center. If the `x` and `y` is not set the car just turns at the same point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please let me know if this is the movement you are looking for:

```js
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
var radius = 100 / (2 * Math.PI);
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var procent = 100 / (360 / 15);
var offset = 0 - procent / 2;

let angle = 0

function rotateCar(){
  requestAnimationFrame(rotateCar);
  angle +=.5;
  car.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', `rotate(${angle},21,21)`);
}

rotateCar()
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 42 42" width="100%" height="100%">
      <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="16" stroke="red" fill="none" />
      
      <image id="car" xlink:href="//cdn.via.nl/img/mainmot/4.svg" x="2.1450689516760377" y="16.912873272286454" width="12" height="5.4" transform="rotate(0,21,21)"></image>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Also in the case you want to center the car on the path you can do something like this:
You wrap the image in a group. Inside the group the car is translated so that is centered. Next you rotate the group.

```js
var circle = document.getElementById("circle");
var radius = 100 / (2 * Math.PI);
var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
var procent = 100 / (360 / 15);
var offset = 0 - procent / 2;

let angle = 0

function rotateCar(){
  requestAnimationFrame(rotateCar);
  angle +=.5;
  car.setAttributeNS(null, 'transform', `rotate(${angle},21,21)`);
}

rotateCar()
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 42 42" width="100%" height="100%">
      <circle cx="21" cy="21" r="16" stroke="red" fill="none" />
      <g id="car" transform="rotate(0,21,21)">
      <image xlink:href="//cdn.via.nl/img/mainmot/4.svg" x="0" y="21" width="12" height="5.4" transform="translate(0,-2.7)" ></image>
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Exactly what I needed